# Shortcut For Right-To-Left In Microsoft's Word Online?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, word-online

As a Hebrew Mac user, [I'm used to Office For Mac without RTL support](https://blogs.office.com/2015/07/22/your-top-10-questions-about-office-2016-for-mac-answered/).

But it turns out [Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx) has this button: [image: RTL Symbol]

As a translator, I need to use it aplenty - what shortcut do I use for it?